# Magento 2 create custom swatch attribute programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, swatches

I would like to create attributes with swatch option programatically in Magento 2.

Comment: By programmatically, do you mean using the API or using PHP coding?

Comment: @SteveJohnson I mean by PHP coding

Comment: I also want solution for this. Have you found any solution then please post here.

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to Magento 1, with a few differences.

#### Step 1

Start by creating a basic setup script for it, if you don't already have one.

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    const PRODUCT_GROUP = 'Product Details';

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State */
    protected $state;

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $attributeRepository */
    protected $attributeRepository;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem  */
    protected $filesystem;

    /** @var \Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media */
    protected $swatchHelper;

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config */
    protected $productMediaConfig;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File */
    protected $driverFile;

    /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory */
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $attributeRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media $swatchHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config $productMediaConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $driverFile
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->swatchHelper = $swatchHelper;
        $this->productMediaConfig = $productMediaConfig;
        $this->driverFile = $driverFile;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<')) {
            $attributesData = [
               // to add in step 2
            ];

            $attributesOptionsData = [
                // to add in step 2
            ];

            $this->addProductAttributes($attributesData, $attributesOptionsData, $setup);
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * Add product attributes.
     *
     * @param $attributesData
     * @param $attributesOptionsData
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function addProductAttributes($attributesData, $attributesOptionsData, ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        // to implement in step 3
    }
}
```

#### Step 2

Secondly, prepare your data. Replace `\\ to add in step 2` comments from Step 1 with something similar:

```
$attributesData = [
    'fit' => [
        'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Fit',
        'input' => 'select',
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
        'required' => false,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'group' => self::PRODUCT_GROUP,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'filterable' => 2,
        'filterable_in_search' => true,
        'used_for_promo_rules' => true,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
        'used_for_sort_by' => true,
    ],
];
$attributesOptionsData = [
    'fit' => [
        \Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_KEY => \Magento\Swatches\Model\Swatch::SWATCH_INPUT_TYPE_VISUAL,
        'optionvisual' => [
            'value'     => [
                'option_0' => [
                    0 => 'FITTED'
                ],
                'option_1' => [
                    0 => 'RELAXED'
                ],
                'option_2' => [
                    0 => 'REGULAR'
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'swatchvisual' => [
            'value'     => [
                'option_0' => 'Fitted.png',
                'option_1' => 'Relaxed.png',
                'option_2' => 'Regular.png',
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

#### Step 3

Finally, finish implementation for `addProductAttributes` method:

```
/**
 * Add product attributes.
 *
 * @param $attributesData
 * @param $attributesOptionsData
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function addProductAttributes($attributesData, $attributesOptionsData, ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
{
    try {
        // Make sure we don't get error "Area code is not set".
        $this->state->setAreaCode('admin');
    } catch (\Exception $ignored) {}
    try {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // Add attributes.
        foreach ($attributesData as $code => $attributeData) {
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $code, $attributeData);
        }

        // Add order if it doesn't exist. This is an important step to make sure everything will be created correctly.
        foreach ($attributesOptionsData as &$attributeOptionsData) {
            $order = 0;
            $swatchVisualFiles = isset($attributeOptionsData['optionvisual']['value'])
                ? $attributeOptionsData['optionvisual']['value']
                : [];
            foreach ($swatchVisualFiles as $index => $swatchVisualFile) {
                if (!isset($attributeOptionsData['optionvisual']['order'][$index])) {
                    $attributeOptionsData['optionvisual']['order'][$index] = ++$order;
                }
            }
        }

        // Prepare visual swatches files.
        $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $tmpMediaPath = $this->productMediaConfig->getBaseTmpMediaPath();
        $fullTmpMediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($tmpMediaPath);
        $this->driverFile->createDirectory($fullTmpMediaPath);
        foreach ($attributesOptionsData as &$attributeOptionsData) {
            $swatchVisualFiles = $attributeOptionsData['swatchvisual']['value'] ?? [];
            foreach ($swatchVisualFiles as $index => $swatchVisualFile) {
                $this->driverFile->copy(
                    __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile,
                    $fullTmpMediaPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile
                );
                $newFile = $this->swatchHelper->moveImageFromTmp($swatchVisualFile);
                if (substr($newFile, 0, 1) == '.') {
                    $newFile = substr($newFile, 1); // Fix generating swatch variations for files beginning with ".".
                }
                $this->swatchHelper->generateSwatchVariations($newFile);
                $attributeOptionsData['swatchvisual']['value'][$index] = $newFile;
            }
        }

        // Add attribute options.
        foreach ($attributesOptionsData as $code => $attributeOptionsData) {
            /* @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute */
            $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get($code);
            $attribute->addData($attributeOptionsData);
            $attribute->save();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw new \Exception(__('There was an error adding product attributes.'), 0, $ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mimarcel, it is always best to post your entire answer so people don't link out to an outside site.

Comment: I have to import attribute option with visual swatch  and swatch value is colorcode. I am following this link for upload attribute options but not getting solution to add visual swatch value. Please help me.

https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-attribute-options-magento-2-programmatically/

Answer (score 4):

Recently tried below code for creating visual swatch attribute options pro-grammatically. Created file within root "import-visual-swatch.php" with below code:

> **Place your all image into "magentoRoot\images" directory and then run below Script**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();

$app_state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Visual Swatch option values array containing name, unique code as key and image url for swatch
// Swatch image are to be placed within "project_root\images" directory
// After code execution swatch images will be uploaded to "project_root\pub\media\attribute\swatch" directory

/* You can create your color name with color image array here replace with your color name and Image name */
$finalProductData = array(
    'BLKV' => array("label" => "Black", "url" => "p2.jpeg"),
    'BLKV1' => array("label" => "Black1", "url" => "p2.jpeg"),
);

$eavConfig = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');

// Generating options as we are creating Visual Swatch hence passing 'visual' as parameter
$data = generateOptions($finalProductData, 'visual');

$filesystem = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');

// Prepare visual swatches files.
$mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
$productMediaConfig = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Media\Config');
$tmpMediaPath = $productMediaConfig->getBaseTmpMediaPath();
$fullTmpMediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($tmpMediaPath);

$driverFile = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File');
$driverFile->createDirectory($fullTmpMediaPath);
$swatchHelper = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media');

foreach ($data as $key => $attributeOptionsData) {
    if ($key == "swatchvisual") {
        $swatchVisualFiles = isset($attributeOptionsData['value'])
        ? $attributeOptionsData['value']
        : [];

        foreach ($swatchVisualFiles as $index => $swatchVisualFile) {
            if (!empty($swatchVisualFile)) {
                if (file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile)) {
                    $driverFile->copy(
                        __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile,
                        $fullTmpMediaPath . '/' . $swatchVisualFile
                    );

                    $newFile = $swatchHelper->moveImageFromTmp($swatchVisualFile);
                    if (substr($newFile, 0, 1) == '.') {
                        $newFile = substr($newFile, 1); // Fix generating swatch variations for files beginning with ".".
                    }
                    $swatchHelper->generateSwatchVariations($newFile);
                    $data[$key]['value'][$index] = $newFile;
                } else {
                    $data[$key]['value'][$index] = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function generateOptions($values, $swatchType = 'visual')
{
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $order["option_{$i}"] = $i;
        $optionsStore["option_{$i}"] = array(
            0 => $key, // admin
            1 => $value['label'], // default store view
        );
        $textSwatch["option_{$i}"] = array(
            1 => $value['label'],
        );
        $visualSwatch["option_{$i}"] = $value['url'];
        $delete["option_{$i}"] = '';
        $i++;
    }

    switch ($swatchType) {
        case 'text':
            return [
                'optiontext' => [
                    'order' => $order,
                    'value' => $optionsStore,
                    'delete' => $delete,
                ],
                'swatchtext' => [
                    'value' => $textSwatch,
                ],
            ];
            break;
        case 'visual':
            return [
                'optionvisual' => [
                    'order' => $order,
                    'value' => $optionsStore,
                    'delete' => $delete,
                ],
                'swatchvisual' => [
                    'value' => $visualSwatch,
                ],
            ];
            break;
        default:
            return [
                'option' => [
                    'order' => $order,
                    'value' => $optionsStore,
                    'delete' => $delete,
                ],
            ];
    }
}

$attribute->addData($data)->save();
```

Comment: Thank for answer buddy

Comment: Thank you buddy. :) +10