# Create Visual Swatch Attribute

Tags: magento2, swatches

Can anyone provide a working example for creating a visual swatch (or even a text swatch) attribute as part of a setup script.

I've tried the example on [Magento 2 create custom swatch attribute programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133237/magento-2-create-custom-swatch-attribute-programmatically) but it doesn't work for me.

**The issue I've ran into there is that the the attribute repository cannot find the new attribute that was created. I tried putting some cache clearing in between but no luck.**

Thanks.

Comment: You can set directly it from admin.

Comment: I'm looking to do this in a setup script.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133237/magento-2-create-custom-swatch-attribute-programmatically

Comment: @AnkitShah that's the one that I've tried and it doesn't work - the set up script cannot find the attribute after it's created it.

Comment: Hi Konstantin Gerasimov Could you Please help to add an image in visual swatch attribute option programmatically. Please help me to do this. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158929)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Parts of this code were taken from `Magento_SwatchesSampleData` core module. Also you might not need `colorMap` but I just put it there.

This code was tested on Magento 2.1.4.

I assume you have an extension called `Goivvy_Custom`. I also assume you know how to install the extension and have magento run install scripts.

The code below will create `new_swatch_attribute` Visual Swatch.

Here is `Goivvy/Custom/Setup/InstallData.php`:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                             

namespace Goivvy\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute as eavAttribute;

class InstallData implements Setup\InstallDataInterface
{

private $attrOptionCollectionFactory;
private $eavSetupFactory;
private $eavConfig;

protected $colorMap = [
    'Black'     => '#000000',
    'Blue'      => '#1857f7',
    'Brown'     => '#945454',
    'Gray'      => '#8f8f8f',
    'Green'     => '#53a828',
    'Lavender'  => '#ce64d4',
    'Multi'     => '#ffffff',
    'Orange'    => '#eb6703',
    'Purple'    => '#ef3dff',
    'Red'       => '#ff0000',
    'White'     => '#ffffff',
    'Yellow'    => '#ffd500',
];      

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
                           \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
                           \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory $attrOptionCollectionFactory
                           )
{     
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->attrOptionCollectionFactory = $attrOptionCollectionFactory;
}      

public function install(Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, Setup\ModuleContextInterface $moduleContext)
{   
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    if(version_compare($moduleContext->getVersion(),'1.0.0') < 0){
     $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'new_swatch_attribute',
        [
           'type' => 'int',
           'label' => 'New Swatch Attribute',
           'input' => 'select',
           'required' => false,
           'user_defined' => true,
           'searchable' => true,
           'filterable' => true,
           'comparable' => true,
           'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
           'apply_to' => implode(',', [Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL]),
           'is_used_in_grid' => true,
           'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
           'option' => [
               'values' => [
                   'Black',
                   'Blue',
                   'Brown',
                   'Gray',
                   'Green',
                   'Lavender',
                   'Multi',
                   'Orange',
                   'Purple',
                   'Red',
                   'White',
                   'Yellow'
               ]
           ]
        ]
     );
     $this->eavConfig->clear();
     $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'new_swatch_attribute');
     if (!$attribute) {
        return;
     }
     $attributeData['option'] = $this->addExistingOptions($attribute);
     $attributeData['frontend_input'] = 'select';
     $attributeData['swatch_input_type'] = 'visual';
     $attributeData['update_product_preview_image'] = 1;
     $attributeData['use_product_image_for_swatch'] = 0;
     $attributeData['optionvisual'] = $this->getOptionSwatch($attributeData);
     $attributeData['defaultvisual'] = $this->getOptionDefaultVisual($attributeData);
     $attributeData['swatchvisual'] = $this->getOptionSwatchVisual($attributeData);
     $attribute->addData($attributeData);
     $attribute->save();
    }
}

protected function getOptionSwatch(array $attributeData)
{
    $optionSwatch = ['order' => [], 'value' => [], 'delete' => []];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($attributeData['option'] as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
        $optionSwatch['delete'][$optionKey] = '';
        $optionSwatch['order'][$optionKey] = (string)$i++;                                                                                                                    
         $optionSwatch['value'][$optionKey] = [$optionValue, ''];
    }
    return $optionSwatch;
}

private function getOptionSwatchVisual(array $attributeData)
{
    $optionSwatch = ['value' => []];
    foreach ($attributeData['option'] as $optionKey => $optionValue) {
        if (substr($optionValue, 0, 1) == '#' && strlen($optionValue) == 7) {
            $optionSwatch['value'][$optionKey] = $optionValue;
        } else if ($this->colorMap[$optionValue]) {
            $optionSwatch['value'][$optionKey] = $this->colorMap[$optionValue];
        } else {
            $optionSwatch['value'][$optionKey] = $this->colorMap['White'];
        }
    }
    return $optionSwatch;
}

private function getOptionDefaultVisual(array $attributeData)
{
    $optionSwatch = $this->getOptionSwatchVisual($attributeData);
    if(isset(array_keys($optionSwatch['value'])[0]))
     return [array_keys($optionSwatch['value'])[0]];
    else  
     return [''];
}

private function addExistingOptions(eavAttribute $attribute)
{
    $options = [];
    $attributeId = $attribute->getId();
    if ($attributeId) {
        $this->loadOptionCollection($attributeId);
        foreach ($this->optionCollection[$attributeId] as $option) {
            $options[$option->getId()] = $option->getValue();
        }
    }
    return $options;
}

private function loadOptionCollection($attributeId)
{
    if (empty($this->optionCollection[$attributeId])) {
        $this->optionCollection[$attributeId] = $this->attrOptionCollectionFactory->create()
            ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
            ->setPositionOrder('asc', true)
            ->load();                                                                                                                                                         
    }
 }
}
```

Here is how it looks in Magento 2.1.4:

[image]

Any questions - let me know.

Comment: Thank you, that works! I had to include an EAV cache clean after the attribute was created. I've propose a couple of edits just to make it clearer for anyone else who needs it. Thanks again.

Comment: you are very welcome!

Comment: Can you please help me i have to add options from CSV with visual swatch value.

I have to import attribute option with visual swatch  and swatch value is colorcode. I am following this link for upload attribute options it's working but not getting solution to add visual swatch value. Please help me.

https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-attribute-options-magento-2-programmatically/

Comment: Can you please help me, How to add text swatch.

Comment: how can we add custom images in this example ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a different and more direct way to add visual swatch attributes. If you check this unit test from the Magento Native code:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Swatches/_files/product_visual_swatch_attribute.php

They propose the following solution:

```
 $attribute->setData(
    [
        'frontend_label' => ['Visual swatch attribute'],
        'entity_type_id' => $entityType,
        'frontend_input' => 'select',
        'backend_type' => 'int',
        'is_required' => '0',
        'attribute_code' => 'visual_swatch_attribute',
        'is_global' => '1',
        'is_user_defined' => 1,
        'is_unique' => '0',
        'is_searchable' => '0',
        'is_comparable' => '0',
        'is_filterable' => '1',
        'is_filterable_in_search' => '0',
        'is_used_for_promo_rules' => '0',
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '1',
        'used_in_product_listing' => '1',
        'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
        'swatch_input_type' => 'visual',
        'swatchvisual' => [
            'value' => [
                'option_1' => '#555555',
                'option_2' => '#aaaaaa',
                'option_3' => '#ffffff',
            ],
        ],
        'optionvisual' => [
            'value' => [
                'option_1' => ['option 1'],
                'option_2' => ['option 2'],
                'option_3' => ['option 3']
            ],
        ],
        'options' => [
            'option' => [
                ['label' => 'Option 1', 'value' => 'option_1'],
                ['label' => 'Option 2', 'value' => 'option_2'],
                ['label' => 'Option 3', 'value' => 'option_3'],
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
$attributeRepository->save($attribute);
```

Comment: its not working