# Magento 2 Create Product Swatch Attribute via API

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, rest-api, swatches

Is it possible to create a swatch attribute via the API endpoint? Swatch product attributes are seemingly created programatically by setting `swatch_input_type` data to the attribute, as demonstrated here:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173528/61629

From debugging, it seems this flag is then used to save swatch configuration data to the `additional_data` field in the `catalog_eav_attribute` table:

```
{
  "swatch_input_type": "visual",
  "update_product_preview_image": "0",
  "use_product_image_for_swatch": "0"
}
```

However, there seems to be no relative POST options for `swatch_input_type` in the swagger documentation of the product attribute endpoint - and also no way to set swatch configuration JSON to `additional_data` field of the `catalog_eav_attribute` table:

- https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/catalogProductAttributeRepositoryV1/catalogProductAttributeRepositoryV1SavePost

I can deduce that this is because there are no relative methods in the product attribute interfaces to get/set this data:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/ProductAttributeInterface.php

The closest I've been able to get to creating a swatch attribute via the API is by setting the following string to the `frontend_input` field in my request body:

```
"frontend_input": "swatch_visual"
```

This seems to create the attribute, but in a malformed state. Product swatch attributes should have a `frontend_input` type of "select". It seems Magento will actually reformat attributes with `frontend_input` type of "swatch_visual" but only when manually saved via the admin panel.

Comment: Github issue has been raised in Magento repo here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28195